# How to Copy Multiple Selected Image from Gallery to Another Folder in Android

Tags: java, android, copy

I'm using  ACTION_PICK to invoke the default Gallery of Android and EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE to select multiple image. Now I'm trying to copy all the selected images to another folder but when selecting multiple (3 or more) images and then proceed to copy only two images are copied.

Sorry, I'm a beginner Android programming.

What is the proper way of copying multiple selected image from Gallery to another folder?

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE) {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                        case PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE:
                    if(data!=null){
                        ClipData clipdata = data.getClipData();
                        if(clipdata!=null){

                            for (int i = 0; i < clipdata.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                ClipData.Item item = clipdata.getItemAt(i);
                                Uri uri = item.getUri();
                                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/";
                                    File f = new File(root + "New Folder" + File.separator);
                                    f.mkdir();
                                    String PictureName = getPicturename();
                                        try {
                                            if (f.exists()&&uri!=null) {
                                                File file = new File(root + "New Folder" + File.separator + PictureName);
                                                 file.createNewFile();

                                                 path = getPath(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                                                    File src = new File(path);
                                                    copyFile(src,file);
                                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Copy File" + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                                            }
                                    }catch (IOException e){
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Toast.makeText(this, "Directory not create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    public String getPath(Context context,Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null,
                    null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

    }

    public void copyFile(File sourceFile , File destFile)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }

    private String getPicturename() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String timestamp = sdf.format(new Date());
        return "Img" + timestamp + ".jpg";

    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm using ACTION_PICK to invoke the default Gallery of Android" -- `ACTION_PICK` does not have to involve any sort of gallery app. "and EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE to select multiple image" -- [`ACTION_PICK` is not documented to support `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK).

Comment: @CommonsWare What should I use ? ACTION_GET_CONTENT ? If you have any idea about copying multiple images selected from Gallery , please share to me thanks

Comment: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does [support `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT).

Comment: @CommonsWare Copy sir , I change my code thanks again

Comment: @CommonsWare I have an error when i change to ACTION_GET_CONTENT ,  but I'll keep searching